# Pivot dataframe in dash table

Tags: pivot-table, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe with many rows and many columns. I made a pivot with this command:

`dati_prev_pivot=pd.pivot(ap_dati_tabella,columns=['prog_anno'],index=['int_id_ait','int_desc'],values=['tariffa']`

so the dataframe is re-shaped like this:

```
prog_anno                                                                  2019        2020  ...  2033  2034
int_id_ait       int_desc                                                                    ...            
MI_ACQ01_02_0043 Campo pozzi, centrale ed adduttrici di Ponte al...   282946.51    79434.75  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_ACQ01_02_0045 Centrale, pozzi e adduttrici Luciani - Sistema ...    95774.45     2970.30  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_ACQ01_02_0047 Ristrutturazione impianto “Casa del Lupo” e rea...         NaN         NaN  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_ACQ01_02_0048 Impianto di trattamento Centrale C1 - Bientina        92221.88  1510676.86  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_ACQ01_02_0052 Serchio Casa del Lupo                                 62801.78   271279.10  ...   NaN   NaN
...                                                                         ...         ...  ...   ...   ...
MI_SII04_05_1479 DEPURATORE FETOVAIA: Sostituzione QE                   2650.76     2194.06  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_SII04_05_1551 Predisposizione nuovi CPI per le stazioni di so...       86.81      418.49  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_SII04_05_1606 Acquisto Attrezzature Tecniche per Servizio Acq...    65203.93    56108.04  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_SII04_05_1617 Adeguamento depositi acido peracetico pratiche ...     6201.33    87615.91  ...   NaN   NaN
MI_SII04_06_0184 Messa in sicurezza di impianti e strutture          1093648.76   670758.90  ...   NaN   NaN
```

Now I'd like to display it in a dash datatable but I don't see the index 'int_id_ait'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRsND.png)

How can I do it?